# Dart HttpClient not reading full response

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a weird issue using the dart HttpClient where it seems like it's not reading the full response before "finishing". This is the code I have:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.connectionTimeout = Duration(seconds: 60);
Completer<MealPlan> completer = new Completer();

RecipeSearchFilter filter = new RecipeSearchFilter();
filter.restrictions = intolerances.map((intolerance) => intolerance.name).toList();
MealPlan mealPlan;
client
    .getUrl(Uri.parse(
    "https://myUrl.com/api/meal-plans?filter=${jsonEncode(filter)}"))
.then((HttpClientRequest request) {
  request.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer $idToken");
  return request.close();
}).then((HttpClientResponse response) {
  response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((contents) {
    Map<String, dynamic> contentMap = jsonDecode(contents);
    mealPlan = MealPlan.fromJson(contentMap);
  }, onDone: () => completer.complete(mealPlan));
});

return completer.future;
```

This is the most intensive function that my app contains, so this particular API itself typically takes 6-8 seconds to fully complete since there's a lot going on behind the scenes. The response isn't big (~60KB). Making the exact same call using Postman I can see that it does indeed return everything as expected, but if I look at the response inside of the `}).then((HttpClientResponse response) {` block, it only contains a very small, partial bit of the response. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I'm guessing that I've configured the HttpClient incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your response will be delivered by the stream in pieces. After passing those chunks through the utf8 decoder, you should then form them into a single string before trying to json decode it. Currently you try to json decode the first chunk without waiting for the rest.

It's much easier to use the `package:http` which is a wrapper around `HttpClient`, and does a lot of the grunt work for you. Also, it's more readable to use the `async/await` syntax rather than `.then`.

Using an `async` method you could write, for example:

```
void getPlan(Map filter, String idToken) async {
  var response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('https://myUrl.com/api/meal-plans?filter=${jsonEncode(filter)}'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $idToken',
    },
  );

  return MealPlan.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
}
```

If you really want to control the connection timeout, you need to pass in your own `HttpClient`, as follows:

```
  var client =
      http.IOClient(HttpClient()..connectionTimeout = Duration(seconds: 60));

  var response = await client.get(
    //etc
```

Comment: Aha! That makes a lot of sense and was very stupid of me to miss :) Switching to the http package was the easiest thing to do. Thanks!